# Is PHP password salt really necessary?

Tags: php, database, hash, passwords, salt

I've asked myself this question a dozen of times.

Is a password salt really **necessary?**

I couldn't find any good literature on the subject.

From a security perspective, do password salts help?
If a database is breached, isn't the salt lost if the password is anyways?

Also, from a brush force perspective, if i ban IP's is there really any reason to store salts?

Comment: You really shouldn't use your own salts on password hashes and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: "Is there really any reason to store salts":  Only if you want to be able to validate the plaintext password against the stored hash.   The salt is a bit of randomness to start the encryption.   Without the salt, a given password will always generate the same hash.

Comment: Yes, they help. Yes, even if the database is breached. Yes, even if you ban IPs. Yes, they're necessary. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should *always* use salts. fortunately PHP is pretty clever. From [this article](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html):

> If you use the default options for the [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function **PHP will generate a random salt for each password** as it is hashed. *The random salt is an additional layer of security which makes it exceptionally hard to crack any passwords*. Even if two or more users use the same password each of their hashes will be different.

This gets you away from having to generate a salt and leaves the heavy lifting up to PHP. The verification piece, [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php), uses the random salt placed in the hash to be able to test against a given password.

From the docs for `password_verify()`:

> Note that `password_hash()` **returns the algorithm, cost and salt as part of the returned hash**. Therefore, all information that's needed to verify the hash is included in it. This allows the verify function to verify the hash without needing separate storage for the salt or algorithm information.

Comment: How does `password_verify` retrieve `password_hash` without some extra information coming from the password directly?

Comment: Update answer @GjertIngarGjersund. If you read the article you'll get a better picture.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: Nutshell:  the hash that `password_hash` generates contains 3 things.   the algorithm used to generate the hash, the salt used, and the resulting hash.   Long answer short:   use these two functions.  DO NOT ROLL YOUR OWN METHODS FOR HASHING PASSWORDS - you'll do it wrong.

Comment: You can retrieve the hashes, but they do you no good as they cannot be reversed engineered. They are one way hashes and your login system requires a password be compared with a hash before being allowed to move on.

Answer (score 3):

You *do* need to salt because an unsalted hash is too easy to crack (using [rainbow tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table)).

First, unsalted hashes result in more collisions. If two passwords used `baseball` as their password, cracking one is enough to crack both. If both are salted, so that one becomes `baseball#sd7#$j` and one is `baseballL4&$h1`, that doesn't work.

Second, a password like `baseball` or even `*4kB$l!h_'` is going to be easy to reverse using rainbow tables if it isn't salted. This is because it's easy to create a rainbow table covering all passwords up to a certain length. If properly salted, though, `*4kB$l!h_'` might be turned into `*4kB$l!h_'H4Sj$8)@80-+2nm:W[oa}u#*4$lNamA{` or something else absurdly long. Generating a rainbow table for that is much, much harder.

With PHP, make your life easier and just use [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php). Whatever you do, **do not roll your own security algorithms,** especially with respect to password storage. You *will* get burned.

For lots more information, read [**Why are salted hashes more secure?**](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/51983/35405) You may also want to spend some time with [OWASP's Password Storage Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) and it's [PHP Security Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet).

Answer (score 1):

it does help against 'rainbow tables', which are precompiled hashes for known passwords. when you salt the password, they are useless, because the hash will be different.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to point out the real purpose of using salts. As explained in another answer, different salts lead to different hashes for identical passwords, but this is *not* the main purpose.

With using different salts for each password, you **prevent building one single rainbow table to get all passwords** at once.

As you wrote, the salt is not secret. To get a single password, an attacker could still build a rainbow table using this known salt. The problem is, that (s)he would have to build a second rainbow table for the second password, because it used a different salt. In other words, the first rainbow table cannot be reused to find other passwords.

Building a rainbow table to get only a single password doesn't make sense, it is easier to brute-force until you find a match, calculating the rest of the rainbow table is useless since you cannot reuse it. That's why we say, unique salts prevent rainbow table attacks, because brute-forcing is faster than working with rainbow tables.

Comment: This is the best answer.